# Filter relationship content by author?

Tags: relationships

I cant seem to get this working on my test but does anyone know if its possible to filter a related list of entrys by author_id using the new standard relationships?  or am I better off using playa?

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="fairs" entry_id="{active_fair}" dynamic="no"}
  {parents field="application_related_fair" author_id="{member_id}" limit="1"}
    {parents:entry_id}
  {/parents}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Im pretty sure i can do this using playa, but not sure that it works with standard relationships?

UPDATE:  so i got it working when i hard code the author_id so it says something like author_id="1"

my issue now seems to be parse order/stash related

here is the full code... basically trying to set a list but within the stash member_id is coming back blank?

```
{if logged_in}
    {exp:stash:set_list name="active_application"  parse_tags="yes" parse_vars="yes" scope="user"}
        {exp:channel:entries channel="fairs" entry_id="{active_fair}"  dynamic="no"}
            {parents field="application_related_fair" author_id="{member_id}" limit="1" status="not Closed"}
                {stash:app_id}{parents:entry_id}{/stash:app_id}
                {stash:app_status}{parents:status}{/stash:app_status}
            {/parents}
        {/exp:channel:entries}
    {/exp:stash:set_list}
{/if}
```

So this full block works perfectly if i set author_id to a specific number... but if i set it to {member_id} it still outputs but its not taking the author_id filter into effect.

Comment: Can you post how you are getting this list too?

Comment: Sure right now its just a simple {exp:stash:get_list name="active_application"}
      Active Application: {app_id} - {app_status}
    {/exp:stash:get_list}

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Stephen and Siebird for all your help working through.  I finally got it to work just using {logged_in_member_id} instead of author_id or just member_id...

Not 100% sure why this works, i guess thats parsed earlier than just member_id?

```
{if logged_in}
    {exp:stash:set_list name="active_application"  parse_tags="yes" parse_vars="yes"}
        {exp:channel:entries channel="fairs" entry_id="{active_fair}"  dynamic="no" parse="inward"}
            {parents field="application_related_fair" author_id="{logged_in_member_id}" limit="1" status="not Closed"}
                {stash:app_id}{parents:entry_id}{/stash:app_id}
                {stash:app_status}{parents:status}{/stash:app_status}
            {/parents}
        {/exp:channel:entries}
    {/exp:stash:set_list}
{/if}
```

then the block thats reading it

```
{exp:stash:get_list name="active_application" }
    Active Application: {app_id} | app_status:{app_status} 
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Comment: Great. I guess I need to update my understanding of `{logged_in_member_id}`. I was dead wrong on that one.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your missing the closing `"` on the `author_id` parameter. Also, the `{parents}` tag needs to be nested inside the relationship field:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="fairs" entry_id="{active_fair}" dynamic="no"}
    {application_related_fair}
        {application_related_fair:parents field="application_related_fair" author_id="{member_id}"" limit="1"}
            {application_related_fair:parents:entry_id}
         {/application_related_fair:parents}
    {/application_related_fair}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Hmm your right about the typo but still having issues... not seems to be a parse order issue.. will edit question to reflect

Comment: I would also change your stash variables names so they don't conflict with the native EE single variables. Also, the syntax formatting in your question is off. Did you update to the one I provided?

Comment: Sure not a bad idea.. same outcome tho... again outputs perfectly when i hardcode author_id.  When its set to {member_id} it still outputs but not taking the author_id filter into effect.

Comment: In your `stash:get_list`, what happens when you add the parameter `process="end"` to change when the data is retrieved

Comment: hmm thought that might work, but same results...hmmm

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE 2 - use a stash embed

```
{exp:stash:set parse_tags="yes" scope="user"}
  {stash:mem-id}{member_id}{/stash:mem-id}
{/exp:stash:set}

{if logged_in}
  {exp:stash:set_list name="active_application" parse_tags="yes" scope="user"}
    {stash:embed:path-to:template parse_stage="both" process="start"}
  {/exp:stash:set_list}
{/if}
```

In **path-to/template**

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="fairs" entry_id="{active_fair}" dynamic="no"}
  {parents field="application_related_fair" author_id="{stash:mem-id}" limit="1" status="not Closed"}
    {stash:app_id}{parents:entry_id}{/stash:app_id}
    {stash:app_status}{parents:status}{/stash:app_status}
  {/parents}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

---

UPDATE

Ah, I think I read your question incorrectly. Does using `{author_id}` instead of `{member_id}` work?

---

ORIGINAL

`{member_id}` is not available inside of the `exp:channel:entries` tag pair because the tag pair is already parsing member data associated with the entry. `{logged_in_member_id}` will not work either. ([ref](http://iamjustinlong.com/blog/single/expressionengine_search_parameter_woes/)).

You *should* be able to use Stash (or even a basic snippet) to set the `{member_id}` outside of the channel entries loop first.

```
{exp:stash:set name="mem-id" scope="user"}{member_id}{/exp:stash:set}

{exp:channel:entries channel="fairs" entry_id="{active_fair}" dynamic="no"}
    {application_related_fair}
        {application_related_fair:parents field="application_related_fair" author_id="{exp:stash:get name='mem-id'}" limit="1"}
            {application_related_fair:parents:entry_id}
         {/application_related_fair:parents}
    {/application_related_fair}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: hmm yea i tried something like that too but no luck...  still not passing properly?

Comment: Are you trying to show entries from the FAIR channel be the logged in user?

Comment: no from the application channel..so one user might have applications from any number of fairs, so im trying to show all their application from the specific fair page they are looking at.

Comment: Do you need the `parse_vars` parameter in the `stash:set` to parse the `{member_id}` variable. I've never used stash (yet), so just trying solutions

Comment: No, you shouldn't. But give it a try. :) Also, if you use `parse_tag="yes"` you don't need `parse_vars`

Comment: hey everyone so i got it to work!  will post solution as another answer